# mdadm reclaimed my zfs storage pool

Tags: zfs, mdadm, zpool

I recently converted a mirrored mdadm partition on Ubuntu 16.04 to a zfs mirrored pool, or so I thought.
After a few days of using the zfs pool, I rebooted the system and the zfs pool disappeared.
"zpool list" does not list the lost zpool.  It only lists another zpool that I have.

My questions are:

> - Can I recover the missing ZFS pool?
> - How to completely remove the partitions from mdadm, so this doesn't happen again?

/proc/mdstat shows a new md device using the partitions that I had used for the zfs pool:

```
md127 : inactive sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      2047737856 blocks super 1.2
```

Before my attempt to convert this device to ZFS, it showed up in /proc/mdstat like this:

```
md3 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
      1023868928 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk
```

To convert the partition to ZFS, I did:

> - comment-out the entry from /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
> - stop the raid partition with an mdadm command (I didn't note down the exact command that I used).

/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf contains:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root@localhost

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md2 UUID=345b919e:df7ab6fa:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
#ARRAY /dev/md/3  metadata=1.2 UUID=a276579e:ac9ae714:8e35cebf:75ca9fad name=...
```

Comment: Try using `mdadm --stop /dev/md127` followed by `zfs import`.  Hopefully it lists your pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the mdadm metadata.

```
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb3 
mdadm --stop /dev/md3
```

Comment: This removed the device from /proc/mdstat after a reboot.  But can I recover the zpool?  It is still missing.  parted shows the partition as zfs.

Comment: `zpool import` - You will see ZFS membership with an `lsblk`.

Comment: Thanks.  This answers both questions.  I edited your answer to make it complete.